# Flask & jQuery: Image-picker doesn't show the pictures

Tags: python, jquery, flask

**1. Background:**

I am new to Flask, JavaScript or web development. I am currently trying to build an interface for a project of mine, which does extract the linear area of a curve. So far so good, my python code works: It reads data from an .csv or .xlsx file and returns the area, it's slope and plots for each sample. Now I am desperately trying to put them in some kind of user interface, so you can decide which ones to plot. I recognized image-picker ([github.com/rvera/image-picker](https://github.com/rvera/image-picker)) as a suitable tool for the job, so I decided to implement it into my project. For this I started to build a simple test-page with the image-picker.

**2. Problem**

Unfortunately, I wasn't able to achieve this. Instead of seeing a list of the image names followed by the pictures, I can only get the list. I will add screenshots of the outcomes.

**3. My Code**

[The project structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zVDWP.png)

Both, image-picker.css and image-picker.js are taken from the [image-picker github](https://github.com/rvera/image-picker)

base.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ url_for('static', filename = 'css/main.css') }}">
    {% block head %} {% endblock %}
</head>
<body>
{% block body %} {% endblock %}
</body>
</html>
```

img_picker.html

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block head %}<title>Image Picker</title> {% endblock %}
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='image-picker.css') }}">
  <script src="{{ url_for('static', filename='image-picker.js') }}" type="text/javascript"></script>
{% block body %}
      <select multiple="multiple" class="image-picker show-html">
        <option data-img-src='http://placekitten.com/220/200' value='1'>Cute Kitten 1</option>
        <option data-img-src='http://placekitten.com/180/200' value='2'>Cute Kitten 2</option>
        <option data-img-src='http://placekitten.com/130/200' value='3'>Cute Kitten 3</option>
        <option data-img-src='http://placekitten.com/270/200' value='4'>Cute Kitten 4</option>

</select>
<script> $('.image-picker').imagepicker();
</script>
{% endblock %}
```

app.py

```
from flask import Flask, render_template

app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('img_picker.html')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

main.css

```
body{
    margin: 0;
    font-family: sans-serif;
}
table {
  font-family: arial, sans-serif;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
}

td, th {
  border: 1px solid #dddddd;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 8px;
}

tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #dddddd;
}
```

[How it looks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z3MM1.png)

[How it should look](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Vt5f.png)
(The website I took the example from: https://rvera.github.io/image-picker/)

If you need any more information, I will be glad to provide it. There has been another question regarding this problem before, but it wasn't solved.

Thanks for any help,
Carroll